# switching from auto-renewable to renewable subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

My client has an app in the App Store that uses the auto-renew subscription type. Upon resubmitting the app it was rejected because they claimed they don't have periodic content (even though they do... but this problem seems to be ubiquitous currently). I was wondering what the best approach is to deal with non-renewing subscriptions. Specifically issues dealing with:

1. Losing your device and restoring your subscription
2. Restoring your subscription to multiple devices (as mandated by Apple)
3. Preventing users from abusing the system.

What I came up with so far is the following:

When a user purchases a 1 month subscription this information is stored locally (say in NSUserDefaults). Also, a unique ID is generated and sent to my clients server. When the subscription ends users are asked whether they want to be directed to the purchase screen. If users wishes to save the subscription in case they need to restore they device, or in case they lose their device, they can opt to have the unique identifier sent to their email address (which they are prompted to enter, indicating that this information will not be used). The app has an place to enter this ID. It will retrieve the subscription information from the server and again store this in the NSUserDefaults. Each time a restore is done, a counter is increased. When it has reached say 5, the user can no longer restore. The same principle described above works in the case of sharing subscriptions over multiple devices. Does this seem like a reasonable solution (and one that Apple will accept)?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use Apple's `restoreCompletedTransactions`? It just provides you with information about ALL the previous purchases, on any device, at any time.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't restore non-renewable subscriptions. See last paragraph of:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW2